# How to lose next and previous buttons on first and last slide?

Tags: jquery

```
  //NEXT
  $('.social-next a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.social').animate({'margin-left': '-=940'}, 500);
  });


  //PREVIOUS
  $('.social-previous a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $('.social').animate({'margin-left': '+=940'}, 500);
  });
```

With this code you can just slide forever, out of all the content to where ever, I couldn't get the buttons to go away, I started getting weird errors. I tried using first and last to juts hide the buttons, but I am not sure where I went wrong and I started trying alternative methods which I am too embarrassed to even mention... I know it's just a simple 1-2-liner though...

HTML:

```
    <div class="social">
        <div class="slide">
        <div class="intro">xxx.</div><!-- <a href="#" class="show-slides">view more..</a> -->
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima error.<a href="#" class="open-slides"></div>
            <div class="content">dolor dolor dolor </div><a href="#" class="close-slides"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima error.</div><a href="#" class="open-slides">
            <div class="content">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div><a href="#" class="close-slides"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima error.<a href="#" class="open-slides"></div>
            <div class="content"><div class="tekst">Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</div></div><a href="#" class="close-slides"></a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using? You should see for an AFTER function callback and put your logic in it.

Comment: I am not using a plugin. I will read into that AFTER thing then and have a look.

Comment: You should use 3 classes: first-slide, last-slide and active-slide.
Code your logic using these three classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in that code to give us a first or last position, the only thing that's being applied is extra margin, so the only way to check position is from the margin.

For example say on the first slide the margin-left will be 0, you can check for that and hide the previous button, on the last slide the margin will be 2820px, so you can check for that and hide the next button.

That's a nasty way of doing it but without changing the markup it's all that is available to you with this code.

EDIT - I've changed the code to use the callback function of animate, as well as a filter to not allow the animation to start while it is already running, this seems to be working very well and doing exactly what you wanted: I've updated the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6S3cQ/7/) so give it a try

```
var increment = -94;
$('.social-next a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.social').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        'margin-left': '+=' + increment
    }, 500, function() {
        checkButtons($('.social').css("margin-left"))
    });
});

$('.social-previous a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    intMar = +$('.social').css("margin-left").replace("px", "");
    $('.social').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + increment
    }, 500, function() {
        checkButtons($('.social').css("margin-left"))
    });
});

function checkButtons(margin) {
    intMar = +margin.replace("px", "");
    var children = $('.social').children('.slide').length;
    var limit = increment * (children - 1);
    switch (intMar) {
    case 0:
        $('.social-previous').hide();
        break;
    case limit:
        $('.social-next').hide();
        break;
    default:
        $('.social-previous').show();
        $('.social-next').show();
        break;
    }
}​
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I check that?

Comment: For example, why doesn't this work:
$('.social').find('slide:first').hide('.social-previous');

Comment: I've made an edit with an example of use, if you make a jsfiddle with the full html/css we can check any issues and iron them out, though that should work

Comment: I think you need to read up on usage of [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) you can't use .hide() by specifying a class as a parameter.

Comment: This actually gave the exact same result :(

Comment: See the most recent update for a full code snippet and a working demo

Comment: That works great, all I had to do what change the '+' to '-' and the other way around as well. Can I change the animation of the button disappearing a bit quicker? When I spam the buttons I can still go out of range.

Comment: I've posted another edit to this, I think it's the most elegant but someone may be able to offer a suggestion for you if it still doesn't quite meet your needs.